# How to convert a date index to string column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I am trying to merge an Excel table which I made with data gathered from `YFinance`. I have tried merging them already but apparently you cannot merge on an index, here is what I tried:

```
import yfinance
import pandas as pd
Dates=pd.read_csv('r/Example.csv)
Dates.columns = ['Start','End']
Stock = yfinance.Ticker('MSFT')
StockData = Stock.history(period='max')
Dates.merge(StockData, left_on='Start', right_on='Date')
```

It throws me this error:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

I tried `pd.concat`and it is not what I need, I need to link up the dates in my CSV with the dates on the `yfinance`. `yFinance` automatically makes the index of their `history` dataframe a 'Date' index, I need to make this index into a column, or at least a string, which I do not know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options here:

1. To make the index into a column you can use `StockData.reset_index()`
2. You can merge on the index using `Dates.merge(StockData, left_on='Start', right_index=True)`
   [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

You will need them to be the same data type. For that it is likely better to convert the dates in `Dates` to datetime using `Dates['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(Dates['Start'])`.